# Flask - endpoint returning dictionary instead of list

Tags: json, firefox-developer-tools

whenever I create an endpoint to return a list, it returns a number-keyed dictionary instead.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
    
@app.route('/somelist')
def somelist():
    return ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

When I go to view the endpoint, I get a dictionary like this:

[image]

What's going on here? I just want a list!

Comment: I believe that's just how Firefox shows JSON output. If you select the 'Raw Data' tab does it show a list?

Comment: I think this is a list with indexes 0, 1, 2. This means a list with three items. First item being a, second b and third c.

Comment: I agree with Andrew. Firefox pretty prints JSON data. Use Raw Data or Headers. See https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/json_viewer/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a dictionary. The `0:`, for example is not part of the response that you've returned.

The browser JSON extension you are using is showing the list along with its indicies.

Instead, use curl or Postman and inspect the raw response without browser response parsing. Or click on the `Raw Data` tab...